# How to query timestamp columns with T and Z in Oracle 11?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

If I do the following query,

```
select dt from table where dt <= timestamp '2021-06-01T10:45:00Z'
```

I get the `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string error`. However, if I remove T and Z from the string, it works fine.

So, my question is, how can I query a timestamp with T and Z here. I need to be able to do that, because the timestamp is returned by a tool in this format (so, I can't remove T and Z myself) and another tool directly uses that in a query. I can however change the query myself. The timestamp there is referred as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `dt` column is a timestamp with no time zone or date and you are ignoring the time zone from the fixed string then you can do:

```
where dt <= to_timestamp('2021-06-01T10:45:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z")
```

or

```
where dt <= to_date('2021-06-01T10:45:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z")
```

If you want to honour the time zone, because e.g. `dt` is a time stamp with timezone, then you can declare the value as UTC:

```
where dt <= from_tz(to_timestamp('2021-06-01T10:45:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"), 'UTC')
```

Be careful with the table column data type though.

---

> And if have numbers after seconds, such as 10:38:10.11956, what would be the format?

Add `.FF` for fractional seconds:

```
to_timestamp('2021-06-01T10:38:10.11956Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z")
```

Not that this won't work with `to_date()` as that doesn't have fraction-second precision. If necessary you can cast a timestamp to a date, or round/trunc to do that implicitly.

The format model elements [are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3); that also shows character literals - like the T and Z in this format.

Comment: And if have numbers after seconds, such as 10:38:10.11956, what would be the format?

Comment: @MetallicPriest - use `FF` for fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method would use `to_timestamp_tz()` and to replace the timezone with an hour offset:

```
to_timestamp_tz(replace('2021-06-01T10:45:00Z', 'Z', ' +00'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS TZH')
```